# How do I subtract a tuple from floats in a function? Gives error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'float'

Tags: python, function, tuples, typeerror

I have a quick question. I want to get three answers when I return the Power function since I have three numbers in my tuple t2. But it gives me this error I can't do anything with. Pls help.

```
t1 = 25.0
t2 = 228.66, 235.6763, 248.161
speed = 100.16
width = 943.0 
thickness = 0.26

def Power(t2, t1):
    "Test123"
    Power = (t2-t1)*speed*width*thickness*6*10**-5
    return Power

print(Power(t2, t1))
```

Comment: What is the expected result of `(t2-t1)`?

Comment: You could use a loop or list comprehension: `return [(t-t1)*speed*width*thickness*6*10**-5 for t in t2]` Or maybe map: `return list(map(lambda t: (t-t1)*speed*width*thickness*6*10**-5, t2))`

Comment: @EliHarold Something like this: (power(0), power(1), power(2)) where every power is a calcuation with a different t2

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Oke, that works. Can you explain why the first one works?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
t1 = 25.0
t2 = 228.66, 235.6763, 248.161
speed = 100.16
width = 943.0 
thickness = 0.26

def Power(t2, t1):
    return tuple((tx-t1)*speed*width*thickness*6*10**-5 for tx in t2)
 

print(Power(t2, t1))
```

**Output:**

```
(300.07951304448, 310.4175661102464, 328.8129441742081)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do it is by using a `numpy array` instead of a `tuple`.

```py
import numpy as np

t1 = 25.0, 25.0, 25.0
t2 = np.array([228.66, 235.6763, 248.161])
speed = 100.16
width = 943.0 
thickness = 0.26

def Power(t2, t1):
    Power = (t2-t1)*speed*width*thickness*6*10**-5
    return Power

print(Power(t2, t1))
```